# How to automatically login to Chrome using PowerShell. I have a script that runs using IE but need to use Chrome

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

#Set URL.

```
$Url = "https://www.plexonline.com"; 
$Username="xxxx";
$Password="xxxx";
$CompanyCode="xxx";
```

## Create a new COM object for IE.

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application;
```

## Set IE to FullScreen.

```
$IE.FullScreen = $true;
```

## Set IE to visible.

```
$IE.Visible = $true;
```

## Navigate IE to the specified URL.

```
$IE.navigate($url);
```

## Wait until IE is not longer busy.

```
 while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) 
    { 
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500; 
    }
```

## Insert the specified username, password, and company code in to their respective fields.

```
$IE.Document.getElementById("txtUserID").value = $Username;
$IE.Document.getElementByID("txtPassword").value = $Password;
$IE.Document.getElementByID("txtCompanyCode").value = $CompanyCode;
```

## Start the login process.

```
$IE.Document.getElementById("btnLogin_Label").Click();
```

## Continue to wait until IE is no longer busy.

```
while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000; 
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use any tool, available because I would use selenium to get this done... https://adamtheautomator.com/getting-started-in-web-automation-with-powershell-and-selenium/

Comment: I did that using a script made in python but it doesn't like several commands. Maybe you can help.  It doesn't like the from command from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import urllib.request

Comment: @Renee - did the below answer helped you solve your problem? If so, please mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google doesn't support COM Model & thus hasn't provided COM Objects to be used in PowerShell.

However, you can use `Start-Process` to spin up a Google Chrome process, and then you can proceed with the rest of your steps accordingly:

```
$Url = "https://www.plexonline.com"; 
$Username="xxxx";
$Password="xxxx";

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($Username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

Start-Process "<path to chrome.exe>" $Url -Credential $Credential -WindowStyle Maximized
```